# Simple file upload - how to add .jpg extension

Tags: php, html

I am creating a very simple admin panel and I want to have posibility of uploading a file, but this is gonna be only one file with static name. I have this code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000" />
Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Send File" />
```

```
<?php

$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename(uploadedfile.jpg);

echo "<p>";

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
  echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
   echo "Upload failed";
}

echo "</p>";
echo '<pre>';
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";

?>
```

And this works, but file is being uploaded with name "uploadedfilejpg" so there is no extension. How to fix this to add extension? I only want to upload jpg files and overwrite old file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an error in your PHP script on line 4. You've got `basename(uploadedfile.jpg)`, which is an error. I assume you meant to write `basename('uploadedfile.jpg')`, but since using `basename` on a file name just returns the file name (thanks to @CBroe for noticing this), you might as well just use `'uploadedfile.jpg'`.

It should look like this:

```
<?php

$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . 'uploadedfile.jpg';

echo "<p>";

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
  echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
   echo "Upload failed";
}

echo "</p>";
echo '<pre>';
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: `basename` removes any path prior to the filename. Using it on what already is a pure filename without any pass doesn’t make much sense.

Comment: @CBroe It didn't cross my mind when I wrote it, but you're absolutely right. I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

replace this line :

```
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename('uploadedfile.jpg');
```

with:

```
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename('uploadedfile.jpg'). '.jpg';
```

Comment: `basename` does not remove the suffix when called with only one parameter.